# Open email client within Ajax callback. Not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, email-client

I need to open an email client via javascript. I need to do this within the success function of an ajax call.

My issue is that this does not work on the iPhone. It works fine when it's not within the Ajax call.

```
function open_email_client(){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", "mailto:myfriend");
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
    a.dispatchEvent(dispatch); 
}

// open_email_client(); Works here for computer (Chrome) and iPhone (Safari)


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myurl/", 
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
       open_email_client(); // Only works on computer, not iPhone. Tested with alert() that it does go here.
    }
    ,error: function(e) {
    } 
});
```

I've also tried:

```
 document.location.href = "mailto:my_friend";
```

This works fine for the iPhone (also within Ajax), but is no good on the computer because I need the client to open in a new window or tab.

I'd like a solution that does not require that I test which sort of device I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it a different way, which was possible because the initial action is a manual click.

Note that the ajax calls has to have async=false.

```
<a id = "email_link" target = "blank_"  >
    <div>Email</div>
</a>


$("#email_link").click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl/", 
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
          $("#email_link").attr("href","mailto:myfriend"); 
        }
        ,error: function(e) {     
        } 
    });  
});
```